# How to execute filter code in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, codex

I have an issue i have put this html code

```
<a href="http://somepage.com/gulfstream-iii/" class="info">Read More</a>
```

But wordpress output gives me this html on the page when i inspect the element.

```
<p><a href="http://somepage.com/gulfstream-iii/" class="info">Read More</a></p>
```

I want to remove the paragraph tag from code which is automatically included by wordpress some one suggest me to try this code.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

i am adding this script in function.php file it works for me but it create other problem remove paragraph tag on other page that make the content worse, so want a solution to run this code by using specific page with condition but when i put this code in page.php i get no result.

```
if(is_page(19)) { 
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
}
```

Somebody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure, that page you are checking is the `ID 19`? Because it should work.

Comment: Try putting that code in *functions.php* not *page.php*.

Comment: @lolka_bolka yes page id is 19

Comment: @rnevius giving no result either i put in function.php or page.php

Comment: It's now fixed i just pasted the code before page loop and now it is working with condition :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will only work if put the code before the page loop.

```php
if(is_page(19) || is_page(461)) { 

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
 }
            get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' );


            ?>
```